# Find first and last occurrence of an item in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with `df` with two columns called `item` and `week`. This is how it looks like:

```
 week           item
 1179           63230
 1179           63233
 1180           63230
 1180           63233
 1181           63230
 1181           63233
```

I would like to find the first and last `week` of occurrence of each `item` in the dataframe, and then compute the difference between last and end `week`. I tried to use the solution provided in this link - [How can I find the first and last occurrences of an element in a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546684/how-can-i-find-the-first-and-last-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-data-frame). The code that I used is as follows:

```
df_start <- df[!duplicated(df$item),]#Get starting week
df_end <- df[rev(!duplicated(rev(df$ITEM))),]#Get ending week
```

But, this does not give me the correct start and end `week`. Could someone help me out?

I am also including an expected output. `df` has about 3 million rows, but the output for the above portion of `df` should be as follows:

```
>df_start

item     start_week
63230     1179
63233     1179

>df_end

item      end_week
63230       1181
63233       1181
```

Comment: Seems to work for me. What's the problem?

Comment: where is the difference here?

Comment: You use `df$ITEM` for the `df_end` code instead of `df$item` - R is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a few assumptions about your data:

- `week` is numeric
- `item` is always associated with at least one week (no `NA` weeks)
- "last" is equivalent to "largest value" for `week`

Then this `dplyr` solution should work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(item) %>% 
  summarise(diff = max(week) - min(week)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 x 2
   item  diff
  <int> <dbl>
1 63230     2
2 63233     2
```

Comment: @Rnovice you asked for the difference between the first and last "week" value by group,  but this gives the difference between the highest and lowest values. These are equivalent if `week` is always increasing within your data, but your question wasn't clear on this.

Comment: Yes good point. My rushed answer assumed that "last" is equivalent to "largest", based on the example data.

Comment: @Spacedman and @neilfws, fortunately for me, the `week` is always increasing in my data, so the largest value will correspond to the last value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `data.table` like this

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(read.table(text = "week           item
                            1179           63230
                            1179           63233
                            1180           63230
                            1180           63233
                            1181           63230
                            1181           63233", header = T))

df <- df[order(item), c(2,1)]

df_start <- df[,.(start_week = week[1]), by = item]
df_end <- df[,.(end_week = week[.N]), by = item]

> df_start
    item start_week
1: 63230  1179
2: 63233  1179
> df_end
    item end_week 
1: 63230  1181
2: 63233  1181
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution assumes it is already ordered.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(df$week), function(x){head(df[df$week == x,], 1)}))
```

Breaking it down. Finds all unique week values

```
unique(df$week)
```

Gets the first row of each week using head

```
function(x){head(df[df$week == x, ], 1)
```

Apply the function to each unique week value. This returns a list of data frames

```
lapply(unique(df$week), function(x){head(df[df$week == x,], 1)})
```

Then we combind the list of data frames using

```
do.call(rbind, list)
```

This can be also modified to be end of the week if you replace `head` with `tail`

Answer (score 1):

Base R version is as simple as:

```
> aggregate(df$week, list(df$item),
          function(x){
            c(first=min(x),
               last=max(x),
               diff=diff(range(x)))
             })
  Group.1 x.first x.last x.diff
1   63230    1179   1181      2
2   63233    1179   1181      2
```

If you really did want the first and last occurrence in row order, then:

```
> aggregate(df$week, list(df$item),
          function(x){
             first=x[1]
             last=x[length(x)]
             return(c(f=first,l=last,diff=last-first))
            })
```